# AngularJS 1.2 Double click required to change the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller responsible for rendering news' page. The address bar does not display the change of the view, and I wanted to fix it by including the following code in the controller:

```
$location.search({pageNr: this.searchOptions.pageNr, pageSize: this.searchOptions.pageSize});
```

It worked fine, now I have the link in the address bar: http://localhost:83/news-page/news?pageNr=3&pageSize=8

However, there is a problem: the content of the view changes only after the second click! I have to click twice on pagination page nr to make the content change, while the url changes after the first click. Where could the problem be?

```
angular.module("News")
    .controller("news.search", NewsController);

NewsSearchController.$inject = ['leftsidemenu', 'category', 'RequestNews', 'forbiddenService', 'urlParams', '$location', '$rootScope'];
function NewsSearchController(leftsidemenu, category, RequestNews, forbiddenService, urlParams, $location, $rootScope) {
    var controller = this;

    /**
     * Default search options
     *
     * @type {{sort: string, pageNr: number, pageSize: number}}
     */
    var defaultSearchOptions = {
        "sort": "",
        "pageNr": 1,
        "pageSize": 8,
        "categoryId": category.id,
        "filter": {
            "keyword": "",
            "donors": [],
            "countries": [],
            "sectors": [],
            "postedYear": ""
        }
    };

   function onPageSelect(page) {
        controller.searchOptions.pageNr = page;
        //urlParams.setUrlParams({pageNr: controller.searchOptions.pageNr, pageSize: controller.searchOptions.pageSize}, defaultSearchOptions);
        $location.search({pageNr: this.searchOptions.pageNr, pageSize: this.searchOptions.pageSize});

        controller.search();
    }
```

HTML - calling onPageSelect

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <da-pagination total-items="searchPosts.totalItems"
                   page-size="searchPosts.searchOptions.pageSize"
                   max-pages="8"
                   current-page="searchPosts.searchOptions.pageNr"
                   select="searchPosts.onPageSelect(page)"
                   hide-per-page-numbers
                   repaginate-flag="searchPosts.refreshPagination">
    </da-pagination>
</div>
```

Comment: PS. I went through similar topics, none of them helped.

Comment: Please share working snippet of your code. That would be easy to debug.

Comment: Hi VicJordan! I have added a bigger piece. When i remove the line of code mentioned first everything works well - I am connecting the issue with my lack of understanding of how $location works

Comment: how are you calling `onPageSelect` function? can you show your html?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Added html

Comment: Have you tried using $scope.$apply to force a digest?

Comment: What is the `<da-pagination>` directive? And how are its click handlers written? It is possible that they are not properly integrated with the AngularJS framework.  Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

Comment: @farvgnugn Keep in mind that in most places (controllers, services) $apply has already been called for you by the directive which is handling the event.

Comment: Works fine in this [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y1KKraneuO7BVtALzhCp?p=preview).

Comment: @farvgnugn Yep, I did try  $scope.$apply, got: Error: error:inprog
Action Already In Progress

Comment: When I remove the call to $location.search from onPageSelect everything works just fine.